# How to save form data in database when submit button is clicked?

Tags: android, database, buttonclick

I am creating one android application in which I am using one form for enquiry.

when the Enquiry button is clicked then application have to show one form . After completing 
the form entry user when user presses the Submit button then the data should save in database 
and form details have to be be send to the admin account via mail.

I am searching in google but I am not getting exact what I want.

Here is my code

Order.java

```java
package com.example.shaktitool;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Order extends Activity{

    private SQLiteAdapterOrder mySQLiteAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order);

        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapterOrder(this);    
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
        final MY_TABLE tb = new MY_TABLE(this);
        final EditText name   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText mail   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        final EditText phone   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
        final EditText product   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.product);
        final String _name = name.getText().toString();
        final String _mail = mail.getText().toString();
        final String _phone = phone.getText().toString();
        final String _product = product.getText().toString();

        System.out.println(_name);
        System.out.println(_mail);
        System.out.println(_phone);
        System.out.println(_product);

        Button email = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){    
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      tb.open();
                      final String _name = name.getText().toString();    
                      final String _mail = mail.getText().toString();    
                      final String _phone = phone.getText().toString();    
                      final String _product = product.getText().toString();

                      System.out.println(name);
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Record Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                      System.out.println(mail);
                      System.out.println(phone);       
                      System.out.println(product);

                      tb.createorders(name, mail, phone, product);
                      tb.delete("12");
                      tb.close();

                  }
              }); 
    }
}
```

can any one help me...

Comment: What part is giving you trouble? Running code on submit button click? Grabbing data from the form? Saving to database?

Comment: Grabbing data from the form?

Comment: If you're having trouble getting the data from the form, have you done some debugging, what does `name.getText().toString()` contain... ?

Comment: Matthieu: I am not getting properly . I am getting struck.

Comment: Now I edited my code . pls see the code and tell me what I am doing wrong in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 EditText fd1 = (EditText)findviewById(R.id.fd1);
 EditText fd2 = (EditText)findviewById(R.id.fd2);
 EditText fd3 = (EditText)findviewById(R.id.fd3);

 submitbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String field1 = fd1.getText.toString();
            String field2 = fd2.getText.toString();
            String field3 = fd3.getText.toString();
            dh.insert_values(field1, field2, field3);   
        }
    });
```

On submit insert values into the database as like this..

and in your datahelper class

```
 public long insert_values(String fd1,String fd2,String fd3)
    {
       this.insertStmt.bindString(1, fd1);
       this.insertStmt.bindString(2, fd2);
       this.insertStmt.bindString(3, fd3);
       return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
    }
```

Comment: It showing the error "The method bindString(int, String) is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: try adding the string values only. i think you are adding Object as string in insert statement

Comment: once can you add your insert code

Comment: public long insert(String content){
  
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
  return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Go through the Below links. You will find good examples:

1. http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-12.html
2. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

And for good SQL tutorial go through this link:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Example  for DBInsert Method:

```
public Marks addMarks(Marks comment) {
        
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MarksDB.MARKS_StdNo, comment.getStdNo());
        values.put(MarksDB.MARKS_1, comment.getSub_1());
        values.put(MarksDB.MARKS_2, comment.getSub_2());
        values.put(MarksDB.MARKS_3, comment.getSub_3());
        values.put(MarksDB.MARKS_4, comment.getSub_4());
        values.put(MarksDB.MARKS_5, comment.getSub_5());
        
        long insertId = database.insert(MarksDB.TABLE_MARKS, null, values);
```

While insertion and deletion from and to the db, keep a modal class get the object from the modal class where you get and set the attributes. Then either insert the current object of the Modal class.  Thats a good and a non confusing way for DBTransactions.